# I am getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException error.can anyone help how to use explicit wait on list?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a link which is inside li tag but i am unable to click the link as i'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException` error.

I am able to list out the Webelements from HTML code but unable to click the desired one below is my code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'menuRoot')]//ul//li//a"));

System.out.println(list.size());

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {

    System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());

    if(list.get(i).getText().equals("Workflow")) {          

        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"))
        );

        list.get(i).click();
        break;

    }

}
```

There is one link in Frame and its in `ul`,`li` a tag unable to click the desired link after switching to frame.

Comment: what is with method `until(...)`?

Comment: sorry it should be wait.until

Comment: I recommend to edit your question and put `wait.until...`. Also `wait.until...` return an `WebElement` with explicit wait on it. So after you check if an element is visible you click on other element...

Comment: List <WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'menuRoot')]//ul//li//a"));
System.out.println(list.size());
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
 System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
if(list.get(i).getText().equals("Workflow")) {
try {
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(list));
  list.get(i).click();
 break;
  }catch (Exception e) {
       
      }
     }
     
     }

Comment: can you please add the html structure of element you trying to interact it will help to debug and reproduce the problem, you facing

Comment: <div class="menuRoot">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1678" shrinkmenu="1"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1678" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="

Comment: http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1605" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain"><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/browser.png">Establishment</a></li>
    <li onclick="selectRootItem(this)" documentid="1653"><a class="menu1" href="
                http://www.intellipen.LegalAndGeneral.pc/Resources/System/pages/read.aspx?DocID=1653" onclick="showLoading()" target="fraMain" style=""><img src="
                  /Resources/System/images/icons/startup.png">Workflow</a></li>

Comment: i want to click work flow

Answer (score 0):

Use JavascriptExecutor as below for clicking element:

```
WebElement element = list.get(i);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: This xpath worked Thanks.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Search')]//parent::li")).click();